# i.e set border to option tag

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I am trying to creatre border to each option element from :

```
 <select multiple class="myScrollDiv" name="selectedGroup"  [(ngModel)]="selectedGroup"> 
  <option *ngFor="let group of  groupOptions" [ngValue]="group"  class="myul-{{group.g}}"  >
         {{group.g}}
  </option> 
</select>
```

my css:

```
.myExtDialog .myScrollDiv
 {  display: block;
    height: 234px;
    width : 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: none;
    background-color:whitesmoke;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: left;
 }
.myExtDialog .myScrollDiv option 
{
     border : 1px grey solid  ; 
}
```

the css works o.k. in chrome but in i.e. it doesn't show borders for the option tags .
how can  i fix this ?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are seeing a grey border in the `<option>` when using Chrome and not in Explorer?

Comment: try to use outline : 1px grey solid  ;

Comment: in chrome the I am  seeing the border .

Comment: I tried outline --> not working in i.e.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately all browsers style their own form components differently so it's very unlikely you'll get the result you want using pure CSS that works across all main browsers.

This article is quite old but the information is still relevant - https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/

It's easy to style the select tag itself (easier if you apply appearance: none; which will remove the browser's default styles), but not to style the option tags.

If you really need to style the option tags you might have to consider javascript.

Comment: can you give an example how to do that . I tried  ngAfterContentInit() {
 
    let el = document.getElementById("myScrollDiv");
    if(el)
    {
        let element = el.getElementsByTagName("option");
       if(element)
       {
            for (var index = 0; index < element.length; index++) {
            var x = element[index];
            x.style.border =   "1px grey solid"  ;
            
          }
       }
      //  el.style.border =   "1px grey solid"  ;
    }

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear, I didn't mean to add the border using javascript I mean use javascript alternatives to the standard dropdown. I normally only style the select tags so I can't guarantee this approach won't be completely problem free but there are some examples on codrops - https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/ - demos here - https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomDropDownListStyling/index.html